# Finding a sequence of numbers where every product of two mod k is unique

Tags: algorithms, number-theory

I want to make a sequence of numbers, where I pick the numbers $a_{0}, a_{1},..,a_{n}$. The length of the sequence is $n+1$.

Now I want the product of any pair of two numbers in the sequence modulo $k$ to be guaranteed to be unique and $k$ has to be as small as it can be in such a way that the resulting set has to be $\{r_{0},r_{1},\ldots,r_{k-1\}}$. So

$$a_{0}a_{1} \bmod k \rightarrow r_{0} \\
a_{0}a_{2} \bmod k \rightarrow r_{1} \\
a_{1}a_{2} \bmod k \rightarrow r_{2} \\
\vdots\\
a_{n-1}a_{n} \bmod k \rightarrow r_{k-1}$$

First I was thinking about using prime numbers, so that the products could be unique, but I have to find a property so that every product is not congruent to every other product.

To be more general: I am looking for a sequence of length $n$ and minimal $k$ such that

$\qquad \displaystyle |\{a_ia_j \mod k \mid 0 \leq i < j \leq n\}| = n(n+1)$.

So a mapping from every product mod k to "a value" filling up every number from $0$ to $k-1$.

Comment: yes, thank you. Also ofcourse no combintation of 2, there are more combinations then number of elements. So just the maximum number of pairs in sequence of two.

Comment: Do you mean the product of two **consecutive** numbers?

Comment: Any kind of numbers in the sequence grouped together like:
{1,8,32} -> {{1,8},{1,32},{32,8}}.

Comment: So you want a sequence which allows $n+1$ different, that is all available, products? That's easy: $\{0,1,\dots,n\}$.

Comment: Not really, what I want is giving a sequence of numbers, making groups of 2 numbers like {4,8,32} -> {{4,8},{4,32},{32,8}}, calculating the product mod n and having the result guarantee to be unique. And that for a sequence of lengte n where i can choose the numbers.

Comment: So you want $n(n-1)/2$ products to be unique mod $n$ (or $n+1$)? That won't be possible unless $n$ is small.

Comment: To summarize: the input is a sequence of numbers and a constant $k$. Find as many pairs $(a,b)$ of numbers as possible (reuse allowed) so that $ab \mod k$ are pairwise distinct. Correct?

Comment: Please clarify the question. As it is, it seems you're expecting to find $n(n-1)/2$ distinct numbers mod $(n+1)$, which is obviously impossible for $n\gt3$. Please give an example with $n=4$.

Comment: Sorry, so ofcourse when n is bigger then 3 there are more combinations of in groups of 2 then there are elements in the sequence, so instead we use mod k, where k is the smallest possible value such that the result is unique.

Example:
{a,b,c,d}
ab mod k -> r_{1}
ac mod k -> r_{2}
ad mod k -> r_{3}
bc mod k -> r_{4}
bd mod k -> r_{5}
cd mod k -> r_{6}
so, find a k such that every product of two pairs maps on a unique number. Yesterday i worked on it using modulo multiplication groups where some congruence classes are relatively prime to k. So far i having found anything usefull.

Comment: Finding *a* $k$ is not hard, if there is one. Compute all pairwise products in $\mathbb{N}$. If they are pairwise distinct, choose the maximum product plus one as $k$. If they are not distinct, there is no such $k$.

Comment: Sure, but will that be the smallest possible for k? I think you can choose your numbers in the sequence in such a way that a "special k" for that sequence will map on the numbers $0,1,2,\cdots,k-1$, and k will be the smallest possible value for k giving that sequence.

Comment: @SanderDemeester Well, we are trying to coax a precise statement of the problem out of you. I recommend you incorporate what you've written in the comments into the question. Note that if *you* pick all ingredients -- sequence, pairs, $k$ -- the problem is likely to be [boring](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2957/finding-a-sequence-of-numbers-where-every-product-of-two-mod-k-is-unique#comment8026_2957).

Comment: I'm sorry, I hope that my question now in a better form.

Comment: @SanderDemeester I tried to clarify the question by improving the language and formatting. Hopefully I didn't mess anything up and retained your intent. Can you please check?

Comment: That is exactly the intent of my question, thank you so MUCH for your help!

Comment: @Juho: Doesn't your formulation fix $k=n(n+1)$? Is that intended, Sander? If so, the question can be simplified quite a bit.

Comment: $k=n(n+1)$ does'nt provide a "relation" with the numbers in the sequence. I think that in order to find the smallest possible k we should think in terms of the numbers in the sequence. It should be something with the prime numbers and there relation to the modulus.

Comment: You can't get $n(n+1)$, since $a_i a_j = a_j a_i$. The best you can hope for is $n(n+1)/2$.

Comment: Voted to close - even after all these comments, we're not really sure what the question is.